# Add QFTP module in qt5

Tags: c++, qt

i want to install QFTP module in my qt5

[image]

I downloaded it from github and i want to know what is the next step, if possible try to be the most explicit because my english is not very good, thanks

Comment: Did you read the `readme.txt`? It looks like a standard QMake project.

Comment: i didn't read it,Note: If you downloaded the source package from a hosting service
such as Gitorious, the package does not contain the generated headers
under the ./include directory. Before building, you'll need to generate
them manually by running the syncqt Perl script. For example:

cd qtftp
<QTDIR>/bin/syncqt.pl -version 5.1.0
what is the steps to add it ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to open qtftp.pro file with QTCreator and then build it?

If this step is completed without errors, you can install the library to the main QT direcotry. Use the QT console window for this, which has all the paths embedded in it. 
Go to the directory where you built the library and enter the command *mingw32-make.exe install*.

After that probably you can use your library in QT Creator by command: 
*QT += name_of_library*

Comment: when i try to build it it says error, QtFtp/qurlinfo no such file